# Word for everything we've ever created to kill

Tags: single-word-requests

> Humans eradicated the plague, but created one themselves - a plague of violence and destruction, which came about with the invention of _______.

Or

> It is a disturbing balance humans have unintentionally brought by pursuing saving and taking lives at the same time. Bringing death through ____ and saving lives by medical advancement.

Basically, a hypernym for *explosives, weapons, TNT, nukes etc.* would suffice.

Comment: Isn't the hypernym *weapons*? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Would *arms* be too simple?

Comment: @YosefBaskin - not all killing devices are *arms* - poisons or torture equipment for example...

Comment: The plague was brought about by the human condition; more sophisticated weaponry merely decreased its incubation period.

Comment: @marcellothearcane why would poison not be an arm?

Comment: @ColinZwanziger *Arms* implies things like 'weaponry, firearms, guns, ordnance, cannon, artillery, armaments, munitions' (from ODO) - I suppose it's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Destructive**
> [dih-struhk-tiv]
> adjective
>
> 1. tending to destroy; causing destruction or much damage (often followed by of or to).
> 2. tending to overthrow, disprove, or discredit (opposed to constructive):

Humans have unintentionally created a disturbing ***dichotomy***; pursuing saving lives and taking lives at the same time. Technology has proven to be both ***constructive and destructive***.

Humans have unintentionally created a disturbing ***dichotomy***; pursuing saving lives and taking lives at the same time. Human advancement has proven to be both ***constructive and destructive***.

Comment: Bare in mind, the same advancements that lead to atomic clocks, GPS, nuclear energy, etc. was also used to create the nuclear bomb. An apropo example of how these two often go hand and hand is that Alfred Nobel, who founded the Nobel Prize awards, invented dynamite.